# Nginx Internal Server Error with docker throw error 500

Tags: docker, nginx, ssl, docker-compose, nginx-config

I,m trying to deploy a nginx application in docker. After I have installed certificates with cerbot i have this nginx.conf:

```json
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name web.com www.web.com;
  location / {
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
  }

  location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
    root /var/www/certbot;
  }
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl default_server;
  server_name web.com www.web.com;
  location / {
    proxy_pass https://www.web.com;
  }

  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/web.com/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/web.com/privkey.pem;
  include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
  ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;
}
```

When I try to access to my web url the browser show 500 Internal Server Error. nginx/1.15.12

I can`t see the logs so I don't know what I have to do.

The ssl certificate works fine becaouse the lock appear in the url bar

Answer (score 1):

Can you check if the container is started or not?

If container is starting, you can connect to container and then check the nginx logs (must be available /var/log/nginx/error.log).

Comment: I can't check logs beacouse it don't show anythig. But I have solved it. Thanks you

Comment: docker exec -it container-name /bin/sh and then check the log file

Comment: @AdrianGago How did you solve it? Please update your question with the solving stuff...